# Accessing iterator value causes segfault 11

Tags: c++

I have a loop that removes Graph edges in adjacency list. It looks like this:

```
void Graph::removeEdge(int a, int b)
{
  vector<int>::iterator it = adjList[a].begin();
  while(*it != b) it++;
  adjList[a].erase(it);

  it = adjList[b].begin();
  while(*it != a) it++;
  adjList[b].erase(it);
}
```

After few tries, i get `Segmentation fault: 11` error. It is caused by accessing to `*it`. What can be a reason, how to fix that?

More info:

```
// This is my structure
vector<int> *adjList;


Graph::Graph(int V)
{
  this->V = V;
  adjList = new vector<int>[V];
  clear();
}
```

Comment: You're not testing if the iterator is pointing to `adjList.end()` so this may be the cause of the segfault

Comment: Presumably one of the vectors doesn't contain the element you are looking for, so you are iterating past the end. You'd be better off using `std::find`.

Comment: Are the indexes `a` and `b` valid in `adjList`?

Comment: Probably you don't have either b or a in the graph and the iterator goes past the adjList.end(). Check if it !+ adList.end()

Comment: Use **Remove Erase Idiom** . That would prevent you from making silly mistakes, such as checking `it` for `end`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The things that can happen here are:
1. Stuck in an infinite loop and (in your case: segfault)
2. Erase non existing iterator (segfault).

To correct these, have this:

Instead of:

```
  while(*it != b) it++;
  adjList[a].erase(it);
```

do:

```
  while(it != adjList[a].end() && *it != b) it++;
  if (it != adjList[a].end()) adjList[a].erase(it);
```

This will end the loop if the element `b` has not been found when reaching `end`, and the `if` clause will make sure you delete an iterator that is existing.

Comment: I don't think that matters in this case. OP is only removing the first occurrence. The problem is erasing the end iterator, as mentioned in comments.

Comment: I did as you said, still the same. Maybe it's something with array. not vectors inside array

Comment: What about just using a debugger? Or at lease give more informations. we dont even know if its an array or a vector...

Comment: Yep, i moved it into some IDE, and it shows that there is nothing inside `it` when it crashes, problem is I dont know why @Nidhoegger